# i keep on getting an syntax error from "int numRoom = (int)cmdSearch3.ExecuteScalar();" part , can anyone help me out

Tags: c#, mysql

```
cmOLEDB3.Open();

for (DateTime counter = startDate; counter <= endDate; counter = counter.AddDays(1))
{
    cmdSearch3.CommandText = "SELECT NoOfRooms FROM + tableName + where Dates = \'" + 
        counter + "\' ";

    cmdSearch3.Connection = cmOLEDB3;

    int numRoom = (int)cmdSearch3.ExecuteScalar();
    numRoom = numRoom - noOfRooms;

    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET NoOfRooms = \'" + 
        numRoom + "\' WHERE Dates BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 ", cmOLEDB3);
}

cmOLEDB3.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want con-cat literal string with var  you should close and open the strings properly

```
cmdSearch3.CommandText =  "SELECT NoOfRooms FROM  " + 
              tableName + "  where Dates = \'" + counter + "\' ";
```

but the use of var concatenated  in sql  is deprecated  because could permit sql injection  ...  otherwise the use on object name, as table or column name,   in dynamic build SQL is not allowed and you can't use binding param ..  so be really careful in control and validate the content of var before perform the concatenation

Comment: Answer  update  for sql injection but for sql object name  (as table or colunn) name the use of   param binding is not allowed ..